How do I separate body content from my side vertical navbar?
I have written some code for a vertical navbar locked to the left-side of my page, but when I try to insert my main title, it puts it in the navbar, rather than the Main content of the webpage, How do I prevent this?
When I put an h1 tag in for my page header, I thought it would put it to the side in the white space, but it shoved it in my navbar as text.
(https://i.sstatic.net/V0G51iFt.png)

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Update your css part:
ul{
    font-size: 19px;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #cfe2cf;
    width: 230px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
    

Add .content-area:
 .content-area{
     padding-left: 250px;
 }
    

in HTML please add:
<main class="content-area">
     <h1>This is the content area</h1>
</main>

Here will be your output


I always use something like:
border: 2px solid gold;

around the elements to see what is happening.
padding-left: 250px;

gets you to the right of the menu, as others mention.
You could also move the entire element with margin:
margin-left: 250px;

Hope this helps!

The updated code seems correct. Define the width of the sidebar and give same padding from left to the content div
